# Ionic framework error

Tags: node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

I want to install Ionic framework on my Windows system.I am already installed Node.js latest version.When I Install Ionic framework on my system its showing error.
 Error:

```
 npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.8.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})

npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})

npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
```

Even installed Ionic command prompt way i am using command prompt for install 
command Prompt: `npm install -g cordova ionic`

Comment: It is just a warning -> ignore it.

Comment: if i ignore.after that its showing error cordova version old please try to update new version its showing @ Aleksandr

Comment: update your node by using node version manager. Read required versions for ionic

Answer (score 1):

I have got same problem and i solved it via following command:

**npm install -g cordova ionic --verbos**

If it does not work then you need to try yarn and downlad yar from this: https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install

After install yarn run following command:

**yarn add global cordova**

**yarn add global ionic**

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too. It means that right now cordova is not compatible with the latest node version. In order to correct this you have to:

- Uninstall current Node JS
- Search for the correct one on http://blog.nodejs.org/3 (it should be 0.10.x)
- Install it

You should have no problems after this. If it keeps you giving the same error, repeat the process again but with a previous version of the one you installed until you find the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Try Re installing

Generally run the latest production versions of node, npm, Ionic and Cordova.
or else change node js version to latest LTS version.

Use nvm (or nodist on Windows) so that you can easily switch between versions.
if you want the different version of node on single machine if you want other applications  which depend on different version of node to malfunction.

Ionic Box for windows : 
use the ionic virtual machine.. to have anything installed you need:
http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-vagrant-android/229